# IIS 7.5 Restrict IPs on a Subdirectory, with Proxy detection

Tags: ip, iis-7.5, whitelist

I have a legacy IIS web server (2008 R2) that is hosting a handful of WordPress sites.  I need to restrict access to the login capability of WordPress (/wp-admin directory) to only a couple known IP addresses.  Complicating this matter is the fact that this web server is behind an F5 load balancer, which overrides the true client IP (although I get the true IP via normal XFF header).

From what I understand there is the **IP Address and Domain Restrictions** IIS module which can allow blacklist/whitelist of a sub-directory like I need, but it isn't smart enough to handle proxy/Load-Balancer client IP translation.  Then there is the **Dynamic IP Restrictions** IIS module, which is smart enough to handle proxy/Load-Balancer client IP translation, but it cannot handle creating rules on a subdirectory (only website-level granularity).

Is there a known way to handle this type of restriction in IIS?  I'm sure I could restrict at the firewall or L/B, but I'm trying to get it done within IIS if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the URL Rewrite module is a fairly straight-forward approach for this need.  Something like the rule below will accomplish restricting certain URLs under a website (e.g., the pattern used can grab only a certain directory if desired).

```
        <rule name="wordpress-login-restrictions" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(^wp-admin)|(^wp-login.php)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR}" pattern="(^55\.55\.555\.555$)" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" subStatusCode="44" statusReason="File or directory not found" statusDescription="The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." />
        </rule>
```